# Dealing with multiple input layer in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-modeler

I would like to add atrribute with **layer name** using field calculator for many input layers and later merge updated layers into one.
I am able to use multiple input layer in modeler and later merge them, but I have no clue how to add field calculator algorithm before as it seems not to allow multiple input.

[image]

I need field calculator on place of red square to add layer name before merging.
There is also issue as data types of inputs are not fully consistent for ID (Int and Int64) taht is not passing merge tool, but merge from MMQGIS plugin is dealing with it alright. Plugin algorithms are not available in modeler.

Comment: The GUI-tool for layer merging adds the layer name field automatically. Are you sure the modeller-tool is different?

Comment: @Erik You are right, but since I had issue with data type I used the plugin tool, that is not adding this field. Now the question should be probably quite different - How to consolidate data types...?

Comment: Run everything through `refactor fields`, but it will take some preparation.